# I want to use Shopify API of "payment" but I didn't understand parameter of "unique token"

Tags: shopify

Thank you for browsing.

I want to use this API's "Create a new payment".

[https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/sales-channels/payment?api[version]=2020-07](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/sales-channels/payment?api%5Bversion%5D=2020-07)

But, I didn't understand parameter of "unique_token". Where can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `node`, from this `npm` package, you can generate the Shopify token as the below link.

https://developer.aliyun.com/mirror/npm/package/shopify-token

Comment: That's a cool answer.
I used "yarn add" and It worked fine.
Thank you very much!!