# I want to use Shopify API of “payment”

Tags: api, shopify

Thank you for browsing.

I want to use this API’s “Create a new payment”.

[https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/sales-channels/payment?api[version]=2020-07](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/sales-channels/payment?api%5Bversion%5D=2020-07)

But, I got HTML on “POSTMAN”.

The details are as follows.

---

Url

```
https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-07/checkouts/0076fd26194e9a11e1ad2fef27e6d369/payments.json
```

Body

```
{
  "payment": {
    "request_details": {
      "ip_address": "114.179.82.76",
      "accept_language": "en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6",
      "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.98 Safari/537.36"
    },
    "amount": "11000.00",    
    "session_id": "east-a2fe97e4239a2141004a2586da22babd",
    "unique_token": "7d80c851451dcbe1d36af87c55c573a3"
  }
}
```

Result

```
<html>
<body>
    <noscript>
        <a
            href="https://accounts.shopify.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=7ee65a63608843c577db8b23c4d7316ea0a01bd2f7594f8a9c06ea668c1b775c&amp;destination_uuid=194909e9-a17a-40dd-bfb7-61a6a8739c9c&amp;nonce=28f174d1a0c3dcad2ee819c1ab6772eb&amp;prompt=merge&amp;redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdrupal-integration.myshopify.com%2Fadmin%2Fauth%2Fidentity%2Fcallback&amp;response_type=code&amp;scope=email%20https%3A%2F%2Fapi.shopify.com%2Fauth%2Fdestinations.readonly%20openid%20profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fapi.shopify.com%2Fauth%2Fpartners.collaborator-relationships.readonly%20https%3A%2F%2Fapi.shopify.com%2Fauth%2Fbanking.manage&amp;state=0ed03b89f02f335f13bdc36f4813a822&amp;ui_locales=en&amp;ux=shop">Continue</a>
    </noscript>
    <script type="text/javascript" defer>
        window.location = "https:\/\/accounts.shopify.com\/oauth\/authorize?client_id=7ee65a63608843c577db8b23c4d7316ea0a01bd2f7594f8a9c06ea668c1b775c\u0026destination_uuid=194909e9-a17a-40dd-bfb7-61a6a8739c9c\u0026nonce=28f174d1a0c3dcad2ee819c1ab6772eb\u0026prompt=merge\u0026redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdrupal-integration.myshopify.com%2Fadmin%2Fauth%2Fidentity%2Fcallback\u0026response_type=code\u0026scope=email%20https%3A%2F%2Fapi.shopify.com%2Fauth%2Fdestinations.readonly%20openid%20profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fapi.shopify.com%2Fauth%2Fpartners.collaborator-relationships.readonly%20https%3A%2F%2Fapi.shopify.com%2Fauth%2Fbanking.manage\u0026state=0ed03b89f02f335f13bdc36f4813a822\u0026ui_locales=en\u0026ux=shop";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

---

I don’t know what I am doing wrong. But, I think the following is suspicious.

I used token on URL “0076fd26194e9a11e1ad2fef27e6d369". This is “web_url”. I got it at “Creates a checkout”.

[https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/sales-channels/checkout?api[version]=2020-07#create-2020-07](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/sales-channels/checkout?api%5Bversion%5D=2020-07#create-2020-07)

I used parameter of “session_id” on body. I got it at “Stores a credit card in the card vault”.

[https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/sales-channels/payment?api[version]=2020-07#create_payment_session-2020-07](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/sales-channels/payment?api%5Bversion%5D=2020-07#create_payment_session-2020-07)

I used parameter of “unique_token” on body. I got it this way.

[I want to use Shopify API of "payment" but I didn't understand parameter of "unique token"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63169499/i-want-to-use-shopify-api-of-payment-but-i-didnt-understand-parameter-of-uni)

Sorry for my poor English, but I want help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your API call is running into issues at API Authentication step. This problem arise, when you are sending cookies with POST request.

From the [Shopify documentation](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/debug-apps-with-postman-for-mac-os),

> Shopify prevents HTTP Basic Auth POST requests that have cookies,
> which can cause POST calls to fail. If your POST call fails, then you
> should try clearing your cookies.

To clear the cookies, use the Cookie manager in Postman app that can be accessed using Cookies button located below the Send and Save buttons.

[Clearing Cookies in Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/cookies/)

For sending authentication information, Shopify uses Basic Auth. You can read more about generating credentials and sending request at [Shopify Docs for Authetication](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/authenticate-a-private-app-with-shopify-admin#make-authenticated-requests).

Comment: Thank you very match!!
I posted again from “POSTMAN”. Somehow I got an error message.

{
  “errors”: “Not Found”  
}


I may be worried.

There is no ”Authorization” in the header of the data I sent.

Where can I get "Authorization"?

Comment: Added info regarding authentication.

Comment: Thank you! I add "Authorization" but, I got the same error message.